# Tools available for visual/pictorial hierarchy of Active Directory tree?

Tags: active-directory

Are there any tools available which can do the following?

- Create visual maps of Active Directory hierarchies.

Comment: I think these should be seperate questions

Comment: Done- they are separate topics. http://serverfault.com/questions/233429/let-end-users-manage-ms-exchange-distribution-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Professional Services has (or had) a tool called "Active Directory Topology Diagrammer (ADTD)"  which creates Visio maps.  It is included in the ADRAP toolset.  Unfortunately, I believe it is not freely available; you'll need to arrange for a "[Risk and Health Assessment Program for Active Directory](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F1%2FC%2F1%2F1C15BA51-840E-498D-86C6-4BD35D33C79E%2FDatasheet_ADRAP.pdf&ei=Z9FSTeKzF4n2tgPI9aSUBw&usg=AFQjCNFPlIZEFwz8R6LMrAap0VgFcyHoqA&sig2=V_0bUWtw7gbv35w2G431PA)" (PDF link) on-site engagement.  It was one of the better "health checkup" services we've bought - A very thorough inspection followed by useful, implementable recommendations.

From the Readme:

*Active Directory Topology Diagrammer (ADTD)
The ADTD is used to create Visio diagrams of the customer‘s Active Directory environment. It can create a diagram of the domains, sites, application partitions, Exchange organization, and OUs. A copy of the tool is provided in the ..\Utilities\ folder.*

Comment: here's the diagramming tool - thanks: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=CB42FC06-50C7-47ED-A65C-862661742764

Answer (score 0):

Those are two ***totally*** different and unrelated topics, the question should really be split into two ones.

About the second one: what do you exactly mean by "manage Exchange email distribution"? If you are talking about managing membership of distribution groups, Exchange 2010 added support for this and for the preventive moderation of messages sent to groups.

Comment: You're right, I created a separate question: http://serverfault.com/questions/233429/let-end-users-manage-ms-exchange-distribution-lists

Answer (score -1):

The built-in MMC tools do it; they are GUI tools.

If that's not a good answer for you, please clarify in your question, much more specifically, what it is that you're looking for.

Comment: Can you provide an info link or screenshot of the GUI tools you mentioned? I do not have access to the AD server to evaluate these directly.

Comment: Nope. If you don't know that basic level of how to administer a Windows machine, and don't have a server in front of you to try it for yourself, this site isn't really meant for you.

Comment: Could you recommend another Q&A site for this type of question?

Comment: Not really. I don't mean to be rude, but the FAQ says that this site is for "system administrators and desktop support professionals." If you don't have even enough familiarity with Windows to know if the native tools will be sufficient for what you're asking, how can we help you? Can you better describe what you're actually looking for or what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why the downvote?