# Let end-users manage MS Exchange distribution lists?

Tags: email, exchange-2007

What tools are available to let end-users manage Exchange email distribution lists?

My Exchange mail servers are version 8.3.137.0.

Comment: Other than Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the blog here](http://knicksmith.blogspot.com/2007/04/delegating-distribution-group.html).

Comment: 5.5, no doubt. :-)

Comment: Added version info in question.

Comment: Ah, now it's better - Exchange 2007

Comment: Take a look here - http://knicksmith.blogspot.com/2007/04/delegating-distribution-group.html

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by "manage Exchange email distribution"? If you are talking about managing membership of distribution groups, Exchange 2010 added support for this and for the preventive moderation of messages sent to groups.

Comment: I am looking to allow end users to create distribution lists. Also, they would like to subscribe to / unsubscribe from DLs. Currently, they must contact IT helpdesk for these types of changes.

Comment: This is fully manageable in Exchange 2010; it's a lot more difficult in other Exchange releases.

Comment: I'm on Exchange 2007 - see my update to the question.